# Jsoup Get Element only if it exists

Tags: java, jsoup, element

I am looking for a possibility to get an element only if it exists. Otherwise I get an error, because it does not exists.

Following case which I have:

- Table with "tr" tags (e.g. 3).
- Code is looking into every "tr" to search a specific data. If not exists, it looks for the next "tr" element. Here, if there is no more "tr" element, it occurs an error.

What I have:

```
Element e = doc.getElementsByClass("table table-striped table-hover nofooter-").first();
Element tbody = e.select("tbody").first();
int j = 0;

while(tbody != null){
   Element tr = tbody.select("tr").get(j); //Look for the next "tr" --> HERE: error, because there is no more "tr", if string "A" not found in all existing "tr"s.
   if(tr != null){
      if(string == "A"){
         //Do something
      }
      j = j+1; //Increment for looking for the next "tr"
   }
}
```

So I need a construct to check, if a "next" "tr" element exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are chaining multiple methods together when you do:

```
tbody.select("tr").get(j);
```

If the first part of the statement, `tbody.select("tr")`, returns nothing, you will get an error when you try to call `get(j)`, since you can't call methods on an empty object.

Instead, break your methods up on to separate lines.

First do `tbody.select("tr")` and save that result into a separate `elements` variable. Then, add a check to see if the elements variable is empty. You can do that by either doing `!elements.isEmpty()` or `elements.size() > 0`.  Once you determine that the variable is not empty, you can call `.get(j)` method on the variable and set the `Element tr` value.

The resulting code will look something like the following:

```
while(tbody != null){

    Elements elements = tbody.select("tr");

    if(!elements.isEmpty()){

        Element tr = temp.get(j);

        if(tr != null){
            if(string == "A"){
                //Do something
            }
            j = j + 1; //Increment for looking for the next "tr"
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The correct type of `var` is `Elements`. That however will **never** become `null`; an *empty* `Elements` is returned then. So instead of checking for `null` use `isEmpty()` or `size()`. Beside this, your answer is still the right way to go (+1).

Comment: @ollo Thanks. Didn't have time to look that up. Updated my answer.